# css - expand width in other direction

Tags: html, css

I've got some icons that expands when I hover them:

```
  .icon
  {
      width: 128px;
      height: 128px;
      background: url(icons.png) no-repeat;
      background-position: left top;
      -webkit-transition: width .2s;
  }
  .icon.icon1:hover
  {
      width: 270px;
      backgorund-position-x: -128px;
  }
```

When I hover an icon it's width is changed, so because of the -webkit-transition is will expand the icon. The way it expands is from left to right which is good for .icon1 and .icon2, but it should be the other way around (right to left) with .icon3 and .icon4.

Comment: That depends on either floating or positioning. Maybe you can set it to `float: right`, or use `position: absolute; right: 0`. Or you could reduze the `margin-left` while growing the `width`. Hard to say without an example.

Comment: Sowmya's answer works also on fredrivett's case, the parent element just needs to have `position:relative;` set for `position:absolute;` to follow it.
Couldn't comment the answer as my rep is too low

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use `position:absolute` and set `right:0` and `top:0`

```
    .icon{
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    background: url(icons.png) no-repeat red;
    background-position: left top;
    -webkit-transition: width .2s;
    position:absolute;
    top:0; right:0; 
}
.icon:hover{
    width:250px
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/J99uQ/2/)**

Comment: this is the best option I know of if you can take the item out of the page flow, but if you want to keep the item in the flow then this solution doesn't work. I don't know of any solution that does though, does one exist?

Comment: is there any solution without position absolute?

Answer (score 5):

Easy! Add one line of code to the element that you wish to resize.

```
float: right;
```

This is basically the same as the accepted answer, but you don't have to mess with absolute positioning and then having a relative container.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/wu6e897j/)

Answer (score 0):

in the previous persons answer, they are positioning the div outside of the view so that when the width expands you only see it one way. That said, i think something where your expanding the width, but also moving the object the same distance at the same time, keeps it in place.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQFMH.png)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34709138)