# Expand the openlayer ScaleLine to the left

Tags: css, openlayers

I try to make the openlayers scaleline expand to the left when zooming, instead to the right as it is in default. The scaleline consists of two boxes: An inner one and an outer one. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494296/css-expand-width-in-other-direction) question and applied the solution to my css code. The result is, that the inner box does exactly what I want it to do: it expands to the left. But the outer box is now just really small and displayed on the top right of the inner one. I added a photo to make it clear:

[image: ol scaleline]

My css code to style the two boxes is the following:

```
.ol-scale-line {
  bottom: 0.5em;
  left: auto;
  right: 0.6em;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1.5px solid #703841ff;
}

.ol-scale-line-inner {
  color: #703841ff;
  border: 1px solid #703841ff;
  border-top: none;
  will-change: contents, width;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

In this state the inner box changes width on zoom, but the outer box does nothing. If I apply a width and a height to the outter box, it changes width and height as expected, but does still not change size on zoom. Any idea why this is and how to solve it?

Comment: to change the default style (left 8px) from left to right your simply need .`ol-scale-line {  left: auto;  right: 8px; }`

Comment: Oh thanks a lot! I wondered why `right: 8px;` does not do the job without adding `left: auto;`